# How to implement PassThrough for pcl_ros

Tags: ros, pcl

I used code [here](https://github.com/Vidicon/2dscantoPointcloud/blob/master/src/lidar_transform.cpp) for 3D mapping using 2D lidar. I want to try to implement the passthrough filter for removing outliers in the obtain points. I tried to replace the **cloud** with **scan3dMsg** in `pass.setInputCloud (cloud);`and result for the program to error. Does someone what should I replace **cloud**with?

```
pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZ> pass;
pass.setInputCloud (cloud);
pass.setFilterFieldName ("z");
pass.setFilterLimits (0.0, 1.0);
//pass.setFilterLimitsNegative (true);
pass.filter (*cloud_filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the pcl documentation. `setInputCloud` is looking for something with type `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr` and `scan3dMsg` is a ros message type. If you want to use this you'll need to first convert the ROS message to a pcl type, which you've asked about in another question; so I won't re-paste my answer here.

All of that being said, you shouldn't be using `PointCloud` messages at all these days as it's deprecated. There are packages that support `PointCloud2`, non-EOL distros, and do exactly what you're trying to do in less steps: [laser_geometry](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry)